# XNA BlendState with SpriteBatch

Tags: c#, .net, xna, texture2d, spritebatch

We are needing a BlendState to act as the following:

- Transparent PNGs are drawn as expected, with anything behind them preserved
- We use `Color.White` to draw a PNG as-is
- We will change the alpha channel of the color to change the "opacity" of the texture

To get this effect, `BlendState.AlphaBlend` is close, but draws white as the transparent part if we set alpha to 100 or any number other than 255.

So we attempted this:

```
        _blendState = new BlendState();
        _blendState.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha;
        _blendState.AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha;
        _blendState.ColorSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha;
        _blendState.ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha;
```

This works, except we now get undesired effects if two PNGs are on top of one another.  Basically we get some weird lines where it looks like pixel data is being added (or something).

Example:

[image]

Effectively, `BlendState.AlphaBlend` is this:

```
        _blendState = new BlendState();
        _blendState.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha;
        _blendState.AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha;
        _blendState.ColorSourceBlend = Blend.One;
        _blendState.ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha;
```

Image looks better than above:

[image]

But then alpha doesn't work, using 100 as alpha would replace the background with white.

What `BlendState` should we use to get our desired effect from SpriteBatch?  We are OK to use a different color such as `Color.Black` there is another way to get it to work.

*PS - another nice feature would be if we could use `Color.Red` to "tint" a texture, but we want it to work in general first.

Comment: Does your first blend state work if you use `.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.One` and `.AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.Zero`?

Comment: Didn't seem to have an effect, it looked the same as my top example.  If I try `Blend.One` on `ColorSourceBlend`, it renders white for transparent edges on my PNGs.

Comment: Hm.. I tried the blend state and it works for me. Have you a small project that shows the error?

Comment: I'll set one up, I could see where this is hard to setup.  (You have to have 2 pngs with transparent edges on top of one another)

Comment: Ok, download an example project here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3702398/TestBlendState.zip I used `#define` to illustrate EXAMPLE1 is my example above, EXAMPLE2 renders correctly, unless you turn on the ANIMATE_ALPHA I setup.

Comment: Did you try to set premultipliedAlpha to false for those .pngs in your Content Project?

Comment: Ok, that works when combined with example 1.  How can I make this work when using Texture2D.FromStream()?  Some cases I pass in a FileStream of a PNG file.  It also happens on MonoGame, which might be a different topic (my game is cross platform).

Comment: PS - answer my question, and I can mark it solved.  Only question is how to do this from a stream.  Here is a new question on MonoGame: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463629/monogame-blendstate-2d-spritebatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `premultipliedAlpha` to `false` for those .png's in your Content Project.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to resolve this issue when using `Texture2d.FromStream()`.

Comment: Thanks anyway, hopefully my new question specific to MonoGame might have the answer to that.  I suspect the same thing will solve it, since MonoGame just loads PNGs from file.  (Although I might try using XNBs compiled from a content project)

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I just ran into this, and it solves the problem of texture loading from file with alpha channel information (similar to `Texture2D.FromStream()`, only with alpha): http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25786/using-xna-contentpipeline-to-export-a-file-in-a-machine-without-full-xna-gs

Comment: Thanks, that is a great post.  Looks a little slow, but will be OK on Windows since it will only be in my "Level Viewer" and not the actual game.