# MonoGame - BlendState - 2D SpriteBatch

Tags: c#, .net, ios, xamarin.ios, monogame

I need `SpriteBatch` to render images how I would expect in WPF or a normal UIKit app:

- partially transparent PNGs render on top of one another, as you would expect
- I have an alpha I can modify, preferably something like using `Color.White` and modifying the `A` value.

Closest has been using `BlendState.NonPremultiplied`, but I get weird lines where partially transparent PNGs overlap on one another.

I was having similar issues on Windows [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450585/xna-blendstate-with-spritebatch), but fixed it by changing the `Premultiplied` setting in the XNA content project.  How can I do similar for MonoGame?  (I'm expecting there is a difference in OpenGL here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved it by using two different setups.

On Windows and XNA:

- Use `BlendState.NonPremultiplied`
- Change the default setting to Premultiply = False on the content project for all PNGs
- To modify Alpha value of a sprite, use `Color.White` and set `A` value

On MonoGame and iOS:

- Use `BlendState.AlphaBlend`
- Leave PNGs as-is
- To modify Alpha value of a sprite, use `Color.White * (float)Alpha / (float)byte.MaxValue`

My PNGs are *not* pre-multiplied and are used exactly as you'd expect coming out of Photoshop.